# elf aarch64 golfed with sys_write

Tags: linux, bash, assembly, elf, arm64

To better understand the `ELF` format and the ARM `aarch64`, I'm trying to create my elf binary without compilers, just echoing bytes with bash.

Will can see my effort here: http://www.github.com/glaudiston/elf

I have succeeded in achieving a fully working elf with `sys_write` and `sys_exit` syscalls for `x64`.

But for `aarch64`, it's not working as I expect it to:

```bash
# cat make-elf.sh 
#!/bin/bash
#
# depends on:
# - elf_fn.sh (github.com/glaudiston/elf)
# - base64 (gnu-coreutils)
#

. elf_fn.sh

instructions="";
instructions="${instructions}\nwrite $(echo -en "hello world\n" | base64 -w0)";
instructions="${instructions}\nexit 3";
write_elf elf "${instructions}";
```

It generates:

```
$ xxd elf
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
00000010: 0200 b700 0100 0000 7800 0100 0000 0000  ........x.......
00000020: 4000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  @...............
00000030: 0000 0000 4000 3800 0100 0000 0000 0000  ....@.8.........
00000040: 0100 0000 0500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 7800 0000 0000 0000 7800 0000 0000 0000  x.......x.......
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2000 80d2 010c 0058  ........ ......X
00000080: 8201 80d2 0808 80d2 0100 00d4 6000 80d2  ............`...
00000090: a80b 80d2 0100 00d4 6865 6c6c 6f20 776f  ........hello wo
000000a0: 726c 640a
```

```
$ ./make-elf.sh 0 && ./elf; echo $?
3
$ cat elf | base64 -w0; echo
f0VMRgIBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAIAtwABAAAAeAABAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAOAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAeAAAAAAAAAB4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIACA0gEMAFiCAYDSCAiA0gEAANRgAIDSqAuA0gEAANRoZWxsbyB3b3JsZAo=
```

It returns the expected exit code, with no illegal exceptions, but the `sys_write` call is not printing anything.

Hiding all `ELF` overhead, we have this:

```
00000078:                     2000 80d2 010c 0058           ......X
00000080: 8201 80d2 0808 80d2 0100 00d4 6000 80d2  ............`...
00000090: a80b 80d2 0100 00d4 6865 6c6c 6f20 776f  ........hello wo
000000a0: 726c 640a                                rld.
```

The exit call is working as expected, so I can hide it too:

```
00000078:                     2000 80d2 010c 0058           ......X
00000080: 8201 80d2 0808 80d2 0100 00d4            ............    
00000090:                     6865 6c6c 6f20 776f          hello wo
000000a0: 726c 640a                                rld.
```

So we have the data `hello world.\n` starting at position `98`. I am very confused about how to do the `sys_write` call here. In `x64` I can set to the next data address that in this case should be `65688`(composed of `PH_VADDR_V(65536) + ELF_HEADER_SIZE(64) + ELF_BODY_SIZE(32)` (without `DATA_SECTION`)")

To the output `fd` I do set in `r0` the value 1 with `2000 80d2`

To the data address I am using `010c` that is `little endian` representation of `0c01` this bits: `00001100000 00001` The last 5 bits are the `r1` register, used to data address.

Given I only have 11 bits
Here I've used the `LDR` (`0058`) but I've tried `MOV` (here `80d2`) too. With no success

I've tried any value from 0 to 2048 where it starts to reports `Illegal instruction` and exit code `132`.

I think maybe `aarch64` does not allow the same trick I've used in `x64` to print data without a labeled data section. I'll work on creating it, but this is just a guess and I really want to understand why this is not printing nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, your string is at absolute address `0x10098` and you need to get this address into the `x1` register.

First of all, `LDR` is not what you want.  It is, as the name suggests, a **load** (read) from memory.  You don't want your instruction to access memory at all, it just wants to put the value `0x10098` into the register.

`MOV` is closer, which writes an immediate value into the register, but the problem is that the immediate is limited to 16 bits, and you need 17.   Because instructions are 32 bits, there are only so many bits available for an immediate.  My guess is that you overflowed this and ended up changing opcode bits instead, so you encoded a totally different instruction.  (Don't guess at encodings!  Look them up.  This would have shown you the 16-bit limit.)

For getting arbitrary immediate values into a register, the intended approach is a sequence of `MOV/MOVK` instructions to write 16 bits at a time.  Here you would just need two of them:

```
   0:   d2801301    mov x1, #0x98                   // #152
   4:   f2a00021    movk    x1, #0x1, lsl #16
```

Though since we are using a extra word, the address of the string will also shift, so you'd have to adjust accordingly.

However, for addresses in particular, AArch64 provides pc-relative address generation instructions, `ADR/ADRP`.  These let you add an immediate value to the current value of the program counter (i.e. the address of the currently executing instruction) and write the result to a register.  As a bonus, they allot more bits for the immediate (though you will no longer need them).

Here we can use `ADR`.  Its opcode is 0 at bit 31, and `10000` at bits 24-28.  The destination register is bits 0-4, we want `00001`.  The immediate gets its low two bits at bits 29-30, and the higher bits at 5-23.  The `ADR` instruction will be at absolute address `0x1007c` and we want `0x10098`, so the displacement is `0x1c = 0b11100`.  Thus the encoding we want is

```
0 00 10000 0000000000000000111 00001 = 0x100000e1
```

---

Some general tips:

- Try writing code with an assembler first, so that you can learn the instruction set and be able to focus on experimenting with what the instructions do, instead of also getting bogged down in how they are encoded.  If you want to come back and do the encoding by hand later, fine, but with an assembler you'll also have a way to check your work.
- Use a debugger to single-step your program.  That would have showed you that your `LDR` was giving you a totally bogus value and might have been a hint that it didn't do what you think it did.
- Use `strace` to see what system calls your program makes.  That would show you (I think, I didn't test) that `write` does get invoked but with the wrong address.

Comment: Can you, please, point me to where I can find the info about the `0x10000` value preceding the `0x98`?

Comment: @ton: The `0x10000` is the `p_vaddr` field from the ELF program header (bytes 0x50-0x57 of the binary), which presumably you put there yourself.  That's the virtual address at which the segment is loaded.  The segment starts at file offset 0 (the `p_offset` field) so byte 0 of the binary is loaded at address 0x10000 and everything increases from there.

Comment: Yes... that is something I was lost too... on x64 even if I set the same value '0x10000' I had to use `1 << 16`. but I think this can be out of scope of this question.

Comment: @ton: I don't understand what you mean, so yes, perhaps you should ask as a different question (and explain fully).  0x10000 is the same as 1 << 16 is the same as 65536.

Comment: it was just me, unable to think clearly. It's so obvious after you said it.